# How to insert money data type from SQL server into currency field in crm using c# (latebound)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

My sample data is like this. **EstOneTimeCharge** is my column name with data type money in DB and `new_estrecurringcharge` is currency field in crm.

```
EstOneTimeCharge
100.20
100.50
100.70
```

I'm using SSIS script component to insert this record into crm.

My first code:

```
if (!Row.EstRecurringCharge_IsNull)
    {
        TicketEnt["new_estrecurringcharge"] = new Money (Row.EstRecurringCharge);
    }
```

Then I got this error: [image]

My second code:

```
if (!Row.EstRecurringCharge_IsNull)
    {
        TicketEnt["new_estrecurringcharge"] = Row.EstRecurringCharge;
    }
```

Then I got this:
[image]

My third code:

```
 if (!Row.EstRecurringCharge_IsNull)
    {
        TicketEnt["new_estrecurringcharge"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Row.EstRecurringCharge);
    }
```

Throw same error as my second code.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use this answer: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b83b6b1d-8e04-4444-b87f-cb45e4581516/how-to-convert-crmmoney-to-decimal?forum=crm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Use both Convert.ToDecimal & new Money.

```
if (!Row.EstRecurringCharge_IsNull)
    {
        TicketEnt["new_estrecurringcharge"] = new Money(Convert.ToDecimal(Row.EstRecurringCharge));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. Still gave me error. My silly mistake when I checked in crm  the data type is text field instead of currency. So I changed to currency and your code is working fine.